# Xubuntu 18.04 - Whisker menu and xfce4-indicator-plugin in xfce4-panel, don't match Gtk theme Configuration

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, indicator, xfce-panel

Xubuntu / XFCE4 panel has many items. 2 of these items are `Whisker menu`, and `xfce4-indicator-plugin`. These 2 items do not match the given Gtk theme background color I've selected, even though the rest of the items on the panel do. I've tried switching themes to all the other themes, but the other themes also do not show the proper theme background color, just white or dark grey.

I've tried setting the `background-color: transparent` in the theme I'm using for the `.panel` css class, refreshed xfce4-panel, re-loggged, with no changes in the problem.

Is there a way to check what parts of the panel are receiving CSS from what CSS theme files? Or is this a known issue that has some sort of fix to get the panel showing the proper theme color?

Comment: I never wrote "Whisker menu doesn't fit" so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

I can't link a picture, but imagine the panel is background color red. The "whisker menu" panel item, the "indicator" panel item, and the "system load" panel item all have black (dark grey) background color instead of taking the color from the "Theme Configuration" red. The them I've chosen (Adapta) does indeed have this black background color, but the xfce4 panel should override this colors in the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global themes are in `/usr/share/themes/`, and should be overridden by the local themes in `~/.themes`.

It appears that Snap apps have their own themes, e.g. `/snap/whatsdesk/17/usr/share/themes/Raleigh`

[Parasite](https://chipx86.github.io/gtkparasite/) should at least be able to source the GTK style of the former.